# Google Chrome Extension Persistence

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

My question is quite simple, i need to develop a Google Chrome Extension and by the way create dynamically HTML/CSS files. Basically i was thinking to do this with javascript but it's not possible for security reason. So i'm thinking about using directly Chrome API.

Is there a persistance API with chrome ?

Comment: Question may be simple, but I don't really get what you're asking...

Comment: I don't understand "it's not possible for javascript reason." why is it not possible? Google Chrome API for extensions must be consumed using javascript.

Comment: Sorry i've edited the post...

The question is just that i wan't to know how i can write a file... Using Chrome API, HTML5, js, jquery ? What's the best possibility...

Comment: I don't know if it this is completely what you need but it is worth a look: http://robertnyman.com/2010/04/22/using-the-file-api-for-reading-file-information-multiple-file-uploads-another-sister-specification-to-html5/

Comment: Could you please explain in more details why do you need this and what kind of task are you solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Extensions use localStorage for data persistence. Check out http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html for a tutorial.

Note that only strings can be saved to localStorage. You'll need a JSON parser/stringifier if you want to load/save objects.

Comment: What i need is save HTML file, and then call them but using an iframe, src=".HTMLFile".

Comment: What you may want is anonymous content injection. http://www.borderstylo.com/posts/220-anonymous-content-injection-in-google-chrome

Comment: It's only a way to insert a iframe on a webPage. It didn't save any HTML file dynamically...

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Perhaps if you provide us with additional details we can find alternative solutions

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with javascript. Chrome is very strict when it comes to calling scripts outside its domain(your extension folder I mean).
1. Make sure you are making js calls from your background page and not your content scripts.
2. If you are making js/ajax calls, note that chrome always sends an OPTIONS request. even for GET requests. So your server have to be able to grant permisions.

I hope these 2 points help your js. However, as everyone is saying, LocalStorage does a really good job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you are asking but take a look at [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html)

Hope it helps!